# How can I highlight cells in a range that match equivalent cells in that same range on another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I've got two tabs on a Google Sheet ('Complete' and 'Required'). I was hoping to use conditional formatting so that any cell in the range B2:AK10 on 'Complete' which matches the cell in the same position on 'Required' is highlighted.

For addition context, all cells will either be empty of contain an integer.

I've tried a handful of things like **=match(indirect("'Required'!B2:AK10"))**, but can't get anything to work properly across the full range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `Conditional Formatting Rules` try:

***Apply to range***: `B2:K10`

***Custom Formula***: `=B2=indirect("Required!"&address(row(),column()))`

If you wish to skip blank cells for a match on both sides then use: `=len(B2)*(B2=indirect("Required!"&address(row(),column())))`